# moving files to folders after they got read and separated by a variable

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, header, fits

I have created a python script that reads a variable `FILTER` from files in a folder and puts the result on screen. However, there are 4 types of variables and I would like this script to separate them all to the corresponding folders. Like move all of the files to a folder named "V" if they have variable `FILTER = V`, if they have `FILTER = B`, then move all of the `B` ones to folder named "B" The script below works to see which files have which filter on screen.

```
import glob
import pyfits
import shutil

myList = []
for fitsName in glob.glob('*.fits'):
    hdulist = pyfits.open(fitsName)
    b = hdulist[0].header['FILTER']
    c = b
    myList.append(c)
    hdulist.close()

for item in sorted(myList):
    print item
```

Result on screen:

```
B
B
B
V
V
V
R
R
R
I
I
I
```

now with shutil the code i run;

```
import os
import glob
import pyfits
import shutil

myList = []
for fitsName in glob.glob('*.fits'):
    hdulist = pyfits.open(fitsName)
    hdu = hdulist[0]
    prihdr = hdulist[0].header
    a = hdulist[0].header['FILTER']
    b = a
    if b == "B":
    shutil.move('/home/usr/Desktop/old/', '/home/usr/Desktop/new/B/')
    myList.append(b)
    hdulist.close()
```

Now this code works without problem but it moves all the files in Desktop/old/ to Desktop/new/B/ however, some files have b = V and other variables so what is the problem here? How can I specify the names of which files have the filters I desired so that it can automatically move?

so it is like from the code above, if c= FILTERNAME1 move to SOMEFOLDER1 if c = FILTERNAME2 move to SOMEFOLDER2 and so on.. I could not write a working code line for this so any help would be appreciated a lot.

Solution;

```
import os
import glob
import pyfits
import shutil

for fitsName in glob.glob('*.fits'):
    hdulist = pyfits.open(fitsName)
    hdu = hdulist[0]
    a = hdulist[0].header['FILTER']
    if a == "B":
    shutil.move(fitsName, '/home/usr/Desktop/new/B/')
    if a == "V":
    shutil.move(fitsName, '/home/usr/Desktop/new/V/')
    if a == "R":
    shutil.move(fitsName, '/home/usr/Desktop/new/R/')
    if a == "I":
    shutil.move(fitsName, '/home/usr/Desktop/new/I/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shutil module to move files.

```
shutil.move(source,destination)
```

Define the source file and the destination files as strings, then pass them to `shutil.move()` like so:

```
import shutil
if c == "A":
    shutil.move(source, destA)
elif c == "B":
    shutil.move(source, destB)
```

I would also recommend that you learn how if statements work. Here are some resources: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm, https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: The problem with this is, when I use my print item code, I see B B B B V V V V R R R R I I I I listed downwards so when i put if c == B and shutil.move(source, dest) i get syntax error, same for c == "B" as well. My c is either B V R or I but whatever I give to c == , I get error...

Comment: @NapolyoN I don't understand anything that you just wrote. I would like you to edit your question to include the full errors you are getting and include ALL relevant code, input, and output.

Comment: here I included the code fully. The one I use with the result and the one I need with the result.

Comment: @NapolyoN You're writing the `if` statements incorrectly. They need to end with `:`.  Please read the links I gave you. What you have also won't work because by the time you reach the if statements `c` no longer exists.

Comment: Thank you, I finally understood them all and modified the code up there too. Here now everything works however, all files get moved regardless of what parameter introduce. I explained the final situation up there in details.

Comment: @NapolyoN The if statements need to go inside the for loop and you need to specify the exact file you want to move as the shutil.move() source. In your current code you only specify the directory it lives in. You are telling shutil to move the entire directory.